# Define a regex, which matches one digit twice and all others once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

As part of a larger regex I would like to match the following restrictions:

1. The string has 11 digits
2. All digits are numbers
3. Within the first 10 digits one number [0-9] (and one only!) must be listed twice

This means the following should match:

```
12345678914
12235879600
```

Whereas these should not:

```
12345678903 -> none of the numbers at digits 1 to 10 appears twice
14427823482 -> one number appears more than twice
72349121762 -> two numbers appear twice
```

I have tried to use a lookahead, but all I'm managing is that the regex counts a certain digit, i.e.:

```
(?!.*0\1{2})
```

That does not do what I need. Is my query even possible with regex?

Comment: I think it is not possible by regex. by regex you can define an structure. If you knew what is the number you could. for example you say I want have two digit 5. but here you want the digits be created base on the digits behind so it is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this kind of pattern:

```
\A(?=\d{11}\z)(?:(\d)(?!\d*\1\d))*(\d)(?=\d*\2\d)(?:(\d)(?!\d*\3\d))+\d\z
```

[online demo](http://rubular.com/r/hXi062uxIm)

pattern details:

the idea is to describe string as a duplicate digit surrounded by non duplicate digits.

Finding a duplicate digit is easy with a [capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) assertion and a [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html):
`(\d)(?=\d*\1)`

You can use the same pattern to ensure that a digit has no duplicate, but this time with a negative lookahead: `(\d)(?!\d*\1)`

To not take in account the last digit *(digit n°11)* in the search of duplicates, you only need to add a digit after the backreference. `(\d)(?=\d*\1\d)` *(in this way you ensure there is at least one digit between the backreference and the end of the string.)*

Note that in the present context, what is called *a duplicate digit* is a digit that is not followed immediatly or later with the same digit. *(i.e. in `1234567891` the first `1` is a duplicate digit, but the last `1` is no more a duplicate digit because it is not followed by an other `1`)*

```
\A                       # begining of the string
(?=\d{11}\z)             # check the string length (if not needed, remove it)
(?:(\d)(?!\d*\1\d))*     # zero or more non duplicate digits
(\d)(?=\d*\2\d)          # one duplicate digit
(?:(\d)(?!\d*\3\d))+     # one or more non duplicate digits
\d                       # the ignored last digit
\z                       # end of the string
```

**an other way**

This time you check the duplicates at the begining of the pattern with lookaheads. One lookahead to ensure there is one duplicate digit, one negative lookahead to ensure there are not two duplicate digits:

```
\A(?=\d*(\d)(?=\d*\1\d))(?!\d*(\d)(?=\d*\2\d)\d*(\d)(?=\d*\3\d))\d{11}\z
```

pattern details:

```
\A
(?=                       # check if there is one duplicate digit
    \d*(\d)(?=\d*\1\d)
)
(?!                       # check if there are not two duplicate digits
    \d*(\d)(?=\d*\2\d)    # the first
    \d*(\d)(?=\d*\3\d)    # the second
)
\d{11}
\z
```

**Note:** However it seems that the first way is more efficient.

**The code way**

You can easily check if your string fit the requirements with array methods:

```
> mydigs = "12345678913"
=> "12345678913"
> puts (mydigs.split(//).take 10).uniq.size == 9
true
=> nil
```

Comment: Great explanation - seems very logical to me! But how do I make sure that this applies to only part of the string (i.e. first 10 of 11 digits). In other words - can I tell the lookahead to stop the duplicate checking one digit before the end of string? Or do I have to use lookbehinds instead? 
I made a mistake regarding the matching example. Another random digit at the end is missing, which would lead to numbers (that should match) like:

    12345678911 or 
    65432198770

Comment: @Amin: If I understand well you want to ignore the last digit when there are 11 digits but not when there are only 10 digits? or there are always 11 digits in the string?

Comment: the latter - my mistake. The restrictions were correct, the example wasn't. So there are always 11 digits in the string, but the last digit should be ignored. The only constraint for it would be \d without the whole lookahead applying to it. I hope that makes it more clear

Comment: This works perfectly and I understand most of it. But I will have to look more into backreferences. Still new in the regex business... Thank you!